# Difference between APPLICATION_STREAM_JSON and APPLICATION_STREAM_JSON_VALUE in Spring framework

Tags: java, spring, reactive-programming, media-type

What is the difference between the following media types in Spring:

- APPLICATION_STREAM_JSON
- APPLICATION_STREAM_JSON_VALUE

---

I found the following explanation in Spring's documentation:

```
public static final String APPLICATION_STREAM_JSON_VALUE

A String equivalent of APPLICATION_STREAM_JSON.

Since:
5.0
```

Ref: https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/http/MediaType.html#APPLICATION_STREAM_JSON_VALUE

Answer (score 1):

**APPLICATION_STREAM_JSON** is the MediaType abstraction over **APPLICATION_STREAM_JSON_VALUE** that equal to "application/stream+json"

Answer (score 1):

The only difference is the type:

`APPLICATION_STREAM_JSON` is a `MediaType`

`APPLICATION_STREAM_JSON_VALUE` is a `String`

Generally we want to use the `MediaType` version when we can (for type safety), but there are many times we must use the `String` equivalent instead.

For example, we must use the `String` version in annotations, because annotation return types in Java are limited to "*primitives, String, Class, enums, annotations, and arrays of the preceding types*" and `MediaType` isn't one of those.